# How to hide the nested class in Web API Model ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to hide a nested class from a Web API response if that nested classes is null.

Please find the Web API model below:

```
    public class School {
       public Student students {get; set;}
       public Teacher teachers {get; set;}
    }

    public class Student {
       public string id {get; set;}
       public string name {get; set;}
    }

    public class Teacher {
       public string id {get; set;}
       public string name {get; set;}
    }
```

Postman Response (if the teacher value is null):

```
    {
      students: {
          id: "1234",
          name: "Alex"
      },
    teachers: null
    }
```

But my expected response is:

```
{
  students: {
      id: "1234",
      name: "Alex"
  }
}
```

I've tried `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValues = False)], [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` but nothing worked. Please advice me how to hide the inner class model if it is null.

Comment: [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)] see: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-5-0#ignore-individual-properties)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify null value handling for every property.
There are a few ways you could do it.

you can add it in the Startup.cs

```
 services.AddControllers()
           .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
           {
               opt.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
           });
```

If using NewtonsoftJson

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
   options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore);
```

Or in the class

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
// or
[JsonProperty("property_name", NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]

// or for all properties in a class
[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```